# Ruby Reverse Currying: Is this possible?

Tags: ruby, functional-programming, currying

Concerning currying in Ruby 1.9.x, I've been using it in some places, and can be translated like basically supporting default parameters to the proc arguments:

```
p = proc {|x, y, z|x + y + z}
p.curry[1] #=> returns a lambda
p.curry[1, 2] #=> returns a lambda
p.curry[1, 2, 3] #=> 6
p2 = p.curry[1, 2]
p2.(2) #=> 5
p2.(4) #=> 7
```

very handy, right? thing is, I would like to be able to curry in reverse, that means, fill the last argument of my proc with a random value. Like this:

```
p = proc{|x, y| x - y }.curry[1]
p.(4)
```

my desired result would be 3. this returns -3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think there's no direct way of doing that and what you're doing is a bit dodgy, there probably is better solution to your problem than back-currying

what you could do to achieve desired result is wrap more procs around your procs:

```
p = proc{|x, y| x - y}
q = proc{|y, x| p[x, y]}
q.curry[1].(4)
```

in fact you can reorder arguments any way you want but believe me it gets messy **very** quickly

Comment: humm, looks clean enough, going to give it a try. The use case is to replicate in a certain place the same behaviour you get from having default arguments on methods, and these can only be set from the last argument backwards. I wanted to take the same method and replace the default argument by a different value in a different context.